# Is the following service layer correctly implemented with multiple repositories?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm new to design patterns and specifically the Service Layer implementation. I need some clarification on where to use Service Layer calls.

Below is an example of what I'm dealing with.  I have data from 2 different repositories so I'm not quite certain when/where I'm supposed to call up any additional information that I need to build my Business Model.

I would like for it to do the following:

1. Find Car in Repository
2. Get Picture from another Repository
3. Update Url within Model to be used for Presentation Layer.

What i'm stuck with is I'm not sure if that logic belongs in the Car Model or it should be handled by a Service layer and within the service layer all of this gets combined.  Hopefully this isn't too confusing. Below I added what I thought was relevant.

Business Model/Logic:

```
public class Car
{
    private readonly IFileSystemService _service;
    public Car(IFileSystemService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
    public Image GetImageFile(IGetImageService imgService);
}
```

Within the Service Layer:

```
public void GetImageFile(int carId)
{
    Image imgfile = _Repository.GetPhysicalFileLocation(carId);
    // ...
}
```

Repository 1:

```
public Car GetCar(int carId)
    {
        Car myCar = this.GetCar(carId);
        // ...
    }
```

Repository 2:

```
public Car GetPictureForCar(int carId)
    {
        Car myCar = this.GetFileForCar(carId);
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: I can review the "Business Model/Logic" part, but everything under it makes no sense, ..why not just post your real code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Business Model/Logic*

These are two distinct things: your *model* and your *logic* should be implemented in separate  classes - the *business model* defines a `Car` class, and the *business logic* consumes it. In other words, I think your `Car` class is breaking SRP.

The way I see it (could be wrong) is pretty much like this (assuming MVC):

[image: pseudo-uml diagram showing CarController->CarService, CarService->ImageService, CarService->CarRepository, ImageService->Image and CarRepository->Car, and a note saying the CarService gives the controller a model that includes an image and a car.]

In other words, `CarController` only needs to know about a `CarService`, which gives it a *model* that contains everything the *view* needs to know - the `CarService` "puts the pieces together" so that the *business logic* "layer" can do its part.

I think having a dependency on `IFileSystemService` in your `Car` class makes that class be more than just a *model*.

Also, in "repository 2":

```
public Car GetPictureForCar(int carId)
```

I don't think it makes much sense to return a whole `Car` from a method called `GetPictureForCar` - I'd expect that method to return an `Image`.

This is even more surprising:

```
Car myCar = this.GetFileForCar(carId);
```

I'd expect `GetFileForCar` to return either a `File` class, or a `string` with the file's name.

Same here:

```
Image imgfile = _Repository.GetPhysicalFileLocation(carId);
```

A method that's called `GetPhysicalFileLocation` should be returning a `string` with the file's name. And to follow C# naming conventions, `_Repository` should be `_repository` (assuming it's a private field).

Comment: Wow!  That's and impressive response.  Thanks again! This clarifies a great deal!  What program are you using for the modeling?

Comment: yuml - see [this meta post](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1830/23788) for more ideas :)